# Autocompletion error during the data frame column selection in RStudio

Tags: r, dataframe, autocomplete, rstudio

I used the `readxl` package to import from the Excel file into RStudio. Now I'm trying to access a column in that dataset using the `$` operator. However, I keep getting the notification:

> (Type Error): null is not an object (evaluating a.length)

Even though I've performed this type of operation many times before without issue...

The error I'm getting:

[image]

The dataset in the Global Environment pane:

[image]

Comment: Can you run `names(costdata)` and add the result to the post? Your list probably does not have any names.

Comment: @Marcelo Here it is: http://i.imgur.com/p23MLnq.png (couldn't add a third image link to the post because apparently my reputation score isn't high enough).

I assume the NA's may be a problem?

Comment: You can copy and paste the text of the result. No need to use images. What is the result of `print(costdata$Quarter)`?

Comment: This is virtually not searchable. Instead, copy/paste into your question code and errors as text.

Comment: @Marcelo and Roman, the issue was resolved by removing spacer columns with no values within the Excel file that were included to increase readability. It seems that columns in data frames read in via readxl must be contiguous. Thanks for your input and effort

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is located in `NA` used as a column name. The error is thrown since RStudio autocompletion is not able to extract column names.

Please see the reproduction of the problem:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3)
names(df)[2] <- NA
```

If you will try to type`df$a` the error below will be generated.

[image]

To avoid this kind of situation you should assign `data.frame` column names explicitly. You have to options:

1. assign `names(df) <- c("a", "b")`;
2. delete the spacer columns from the source Excel file to avoid `NA` use as the column names.